# promtheus adapter does not capture my custom metric

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I try to get a metric in kubernetes using prometheus adapter. this is my metric

```
rabbitmq_queue_messages{cluster="my-rabbitmq", container="rabbitmq-exporter", durable="false", endpoint="metrics", instance="10.244.0.23:9419", job="default/rabbitmq-exporter", namespace="default", pod="rabbitmq-exporter-deployment-5684699d6c-9rwgg", queue="my_queue", self="1", vhost="/"}
```

and this is my configuration(it has been saved in a configmap) for prometheus adapter

```
    "rules":
      - "seriesQuery": "rabbitmq_queue_messages"
        "resources":
          "overrides":
            "kubernetes_namespace":
              "resource": "namespace"
            "kubernetes_pod_name": 
              "resource": "pod"
        "name":
          "matches": "rabbitmq_queue_messages"
          "as": "rabbitmq_queue_messages"
        "metricsQuery": "rabbitmq_queue_messages"
```

and it's not working I also try this config without metricsQuery and name but it didn't work is there anything that i miss here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turn out that i need a cluster role that allow me to produce custom metrics. I create this clusterrole

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: metrics-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/name: prometheus-adapter
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: kube-prometheus
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 0.11.2
  name: prometheus-adapter
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - ""
  resources:
  - nodes
  - namespaces
  - pods
  - services
  verbs:
  - get
  - list
  - watch
- apiGroups:
  - custom.metrics.k8s.io
  resources:
  - '*'
  verbs:
  - '*'
```